# How to echo JSON data using PHP

Tags: php, json

```
{
  USD_INR: {
    2017-12-31: 63.830002
  },
  INR_USD: {
    2017-12-31: 0.015667
  }
}
```

I have tried with following method,

```
$url = file_get_contents("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_INR,INR_USD&compact=ultra&date=2017-12-31");
$result = json_decode($url);
echo $result->USD_INR;
```

but it did't works, can any one help me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What are you currently getting as a result?

Comment: `echo $result->USD_INR->{'2017-12-31'};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass date in `$todaysDate` variable which you want price.

```
$todaysDate = "2017-12-31";
$url = file_get_contents("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_INR,INR_USD&compact=ultra&date=$todaysDate");
$result = json_decode($url);

echo ($result->USD_INR->$todaysDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `true` as a second parameter on `json_decode` to make it associative array.

```
$url = file_get_contents("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_INR,INR_USD&compact=ultra&date=2017-12-31");
$result = json_decode($url, true);
```

And access it as:

```
echo $result["USD_INR"]["2017-12-31"];
```

This will result to: `63.830002`

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

---

You can `foreach` loop to get all the values

```
$url = file_get_contents("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_INR,INR_USD&compact=ultra&date=2017-12-31");
$result = json_decode($url, true);

foreach ( $result as $value ) {
    foreach ( $value as $date => $rate ) {
        echo $date . ": " . $rate . "<br />";
    }
}
```

This will result to:

```
2017-12-31: 63.830002
2017-12-31: 0.015667
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to echo an object either use `print_r` like this to print `USD_INR`

```
$url = '{"USD_INR":{"2017-12-31":63.830002},"INR_USD":{"2017-12-31":0.015667}}';
$result = json_decode($url);
print_r($result->USD_INR);
```

OR to echo value of `2017-12-31` inside `USD_INR`

```
$url = '{"USD_INR":{"2017-12-31":63.830002},"INR_USD":{"2017-12-31":0.015667}}';
$result = json_decode($url);
echo $result->USD_INR->{'2017-12-31'};
```

Using `{'2017-12-31'}` because `2017-12-31` is not proper [variable name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

[Live demo](https://eval.in/951257)